# Swift, iOS: what to do in file access catch

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, avaudioplayer, nsurl

I currently have this (which I basically copied from an example) in my Swift iOS app, which I have been building and testing in Xcode:

```
            let s1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioFile as? String, ofType: "mp3")!)
            do {
                audioPlayers.player1 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:s1)
            } catch {
            print("Error getting the audio file 1")
            }
```

What should I do in the catch statement for the version I submit to the App Store?

Comment: Just handle error in `catch`  block.

Comment: Exactly. In a shipping application, you might fall back on a default file, or you show an alert to the user, informing them something went wrong and how/if they could fix it.